# What is the modern equivalent (C++) style for the older (C-like) fscanf method?

Tags: c++, c, scanf

What is the best option if I want to "upgrade" old C-code to newer C++ when reading a file with a semicolon delimiter:

```
/* reading in from file C-like: */
fscanf(tFile, "%d", &mypost.nr); /*delimiter ; */
fscanf(tFile, " ;%[^;];", mypost.aftername);/* delimiter ; */
fscanf(tFile, " %[^;]", mypost.forename);   /*delimiter ; */
fscanf(tFile, " ;%[^;];", mypost.dept);/*delimiter ; */
fscanf(tFile, " %[^;];", mypost.position);/* delimiter ; */
fscanf(tFile, "%d", &mypost.nr2);

//eqivalent best C++ method achieving the same thing?
```

Comment: I wonder how strict fscanf is? If you read all characters up to a semicolon on the line with forename, how can the next line read a space before the semicolon? - Also, `fscanf` probably wouldn't that bad if you could also specify the maximum number of characters to read somewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could overload the right-shift operator on istream for your struct, so:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, mypost_struct& mps) {
    is >> mps.nr;
    is.ignore(1, ';');
    is.getline(mps.forename, 255, ';');
    is.getline(mps.aftername, 255, ';');
    is >> mps.dept;
    is.ignore(1, ';');
    is >> mps.position;
    is.ignore(1, ';');
    is >> mps.nr2;

    return is;
}
```

Subsequently, input is as simple as `is >> mypost;`, where `is` is the file that you have opened.

Edit: @UncleBens Thanks for pointing this out, I had forgotten to take spaces in account. I have updated the answer, assuming that forename and aftername are likely to contain spaces. And there was this rather embarrasing bit about the delimiters being double-quoted...

I just checked it using a struct definition as under:

```
struct mypost_struct {
    int nr;
    char forename[255], aftername[255];
    int dept, position, nr2;
};
```

.. and the result was as expected.

Comment: I wonder what all the upvotes are for. The idea of providing overloaded `>>` is fine but the implementation (**how** to read delimited input) is completely broken. `ignore` doesn't have this form, and even if you fix it this won't change the behavior of `istream.operator>>` and use ";" as a delimiter. It would sort of work if the input is also delimited with whitespace and none of the strings contain more than one word.

Answer (score 3):

As @susmits says, but you can also use the returned stream as a conditional, like:

```
if (is >> mps.nr && is.ignore(1, ";") && is >> mps.aftername && ...) {
   // all is well ...
} else {
   // bad input format
}
```

or even:

```
if (is >> mps.nr >> ignore(";") >> mps.aftername >> ...) {
    // all is well ...
} else {
    // bad input format
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best option if I want to
>   "upgrade" old C-code to newer C++...?

IMHO, the best way to do this would be to read the file line-by-line and use [regular expressions for parsing](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/example/snippets/captures_example.cpp).