# C++ equivalent of fscanf()?

Tags: c++, c, file-io

And please don't say it's fscanf() ;P

I'm trying to replace this line:

```
if ( fscanf(fp, "P%c\n", &ch) != 1 )
```

If I understand correctly, it tries to read in a char and store it to &ch, only if it's between a 'P' and  a '\n'. Is that right?
And if it succeeds, it returns 1 (the number of characters it read)?

I'm trying to come up with a C++ version. Is there any easy way to do a formatted read like that? Or do I need to use fstream, operator>>, and nested if statements?

Comment: fscanf is a perfectly cromulent C++ function.  What's your objection to using it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537500/what-is-the-modern-equivalent-c-style-for-the-older-c-like-fscanf-method

Comment: If fscanf() is fine to use in C++, why does my compiler tell me it's unsafe? :-(

Comment: What compiler are you using? I'm not sure, but I think that there are some functions that the VS compiler consider unsafe but I think that the same warning would occur if you were compiling a pure C program.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010, so whichever compiler came with that. I need this to run on Mac and possibly linux systems as well, preferably building without warnings...

Comment: VC++ considers it unsafe because it relies on the existence of a `null` terminator.  It prefers if you use (the non-standard) `fscanf_s`.  To suppress the warning, you can place `#pragma warning(suppress:4996)` on the lines immediately before calling `fscanf`.  Non-MSVC compilers won't understand this statement, but should ignore it.  g++ does.

Answer (score 4):

Safe C++ alternative with type checks is [std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/).

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at this a bit, but I can't seem to find a way to format the input like fscanf did ("P%c\n"). Am I stuck doing it the tedious way?

Comment: I think that you can use stringstream to read the whole line as a string. Then you can get you char at the proper position in you string.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, the safe, but non-portable, equivalent function is fscanf_s.

In general, for portability, you would use one of the stream classes, which, as you note, can be a pain to format correctly.