# c++ Reading a text file into ints and strings

Tags: c++, integer, iostream

I have the standard reading in of a text file but what I need is the first 3 characters of a line to be read in as int and the remainder of the line as a string on a line by line basis. I've put the code below with the example text.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
 char buffer[256];
 ifstream myfile ("example.txt");

  while (! myfile.eof() )
  {
    myfile.getline (buffer,100);
    cout << buffer << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What example text? And that code doesn't do anything like what you are asking about, and is in any case wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (pseudo code, I'm sure you can figure out the real operations!)

```
std::string line;
ifstream myfile ("example.txt");

// this gets a line of text from the file.
while(std::getline(myfile, line))
{
  // now you need to extract three characters and convert to int, so is it always guranteed?
  if (line.size() > 3)
  {
    std::string int_s = <substring from 0, size: 3>; // lookup this function in a reference!
    std::string rest_s = <substring from 3 to end>; // ditto for the lookup

    // now convert the integer part.
    long int int_v = <conversion routine, hint: strtol>; // lookup syntax in reference.
    // use...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327112/c-equivalent-of-fscanf) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537500/what-is-the-modern-equivalent-c-style-for-the-older-c-like-fscanf-method) from stackoverflow.

Either you use sscanf on your buffer (supposing your string if NULL terminated) specifying a format string like this: `"%d%s"`, or you use 
`operator<<` from [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/).

NB: In case your string include white spaces, you should use "%d%n" instead of "%d%s" with sscanf, like here:

```
     int val = 0;
 int pos = 0;
 sscanf(buffer, "%d%n", &val, &pos);

 std::cout << "integer: " << val << std::endl;
 std::cout << "string: " << buffer+pos << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I'd actually recommend Boost Spirit (Qi), see below later for an example

```
   #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int main () 
    {
        ifstream myfile ("example.txt");

        std::string line;
        while ( std::getline(myfile, line) )
        {
            std::istringstream iss(line.substr(0,3));
            int i;
            if (!(iss >> i))
            {
                i = -1;
                // TODO handle error
            }

            std::string tail = line.size()<4? "" : line.substr(4);
            std::cout << "int: " << i << ", tail: " << tail << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Just for fun, here is a more flexible Boost based solution:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    ifstream myfile ("example.txt");

    std::string line;
    while ( std::getline(myfile, line) )
    {
        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

        std::string::iterator b(line.begin()), e(line.end());

        int i = -1; std::string tail;
        if (phrase_parse(b, e, int_ >> *char_, space, i, tail))
            std::cout << "int: " << i << ", tail: " << tail << std::endl;
        // else // TODO handle error
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you really *must* have the first three characters as integers, i'd stick with the pure STL solution for now

Comment: argh.. you've completely negated my answer!!! :) I did not provide all the code, just pseudo... ah well...

Answer (score 0):

Use fscanf:

```
char str[256];
int  num = 0;

FILE *myFile = (FILE*) calloc(1, sizeof(FILE);
myFile = fopen("example.txt, "r");

while (fscanf(myFile, "%d %s\n", &num, str))
{
  printf("%d, %s\n", num str);
}
```

Comment: eh? what's the purpose of the `calloc()`? Anways, the OP states that only the first *three characters* form the int, it's *not* separated by a space..

Comment: this would read the string only to the first whitespace. so if the line was "1 stack overflow", str would only contain "stack"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are assuming MAX length of line is 100 chars.

`char szInt[4];

strncpy(szInt, buffer, 3);

szInt[3] = 0;

buffer += 3;

int errCode = atoi(szInt);`

*errCode* has your int and *buffer* has your string now.